# Query changing strings to ints in mongoDB takes a long time

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I run the following query on my whole data set(approx. 3 million documents) in mongoDB to change user IDs that are strings into ints. This query does not seem to  complete:

```
var cursor = db.play_sessions.find()

while (cursor.hasNext()) { 
  var play = cursor.next(); 
  db.play_sessions.update({_id : play._id}, {$set : {user_id : new NumberInt(play.user_id) }});
}
```

I run this query on the same data set and it returns relatively quickly:

```
db.play_sessions.find().forEach(function(play){
    if (play.score && play.user_id && play.user_attempt_no && play.game_id && play.level && play.training_session_id) {
        print(play.score,",",play.user_id,",",play.user_attempt_no,",",play.game_id,",",play.level,",",parseInt(play.training_session_id).toFixed());
    } else if (play.score && play.user_id && play.user_attempt_no && play.game_id && play.level) {
        print(play.score,",",play.user_id,",",play.user_attempt_no,",",play.game_id,",",play.level);
    };
});
```

I understand I am writing to the database in the first query but why does the first query never seem to return, while the second does so relatively quickly? Is there something wrong with the code in the first query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three million documents is quite a lot of documents so the whole operation is going to take a while. But the main thing here to consider is that you are asking to both "send" data to the database and "receive" a acknowledged write response ( because that is what happens ) three million times. That alone is a lot more waiting in between operations than simply iterating a cursor.

Another reason here is that it is very likely that you are running MongoDB 2.6 or a greater revision. There is a core difference between earlier versions and versions upward to how this code is processed in the shell. The core of this is the [Bulk Operations API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) which contains methods that are actually used by all the shell helpers for **all** interaction with the database.

In prior versions, in such a "loop" operation the "write concern" acknowledgement was not done in this context for each iteration. The way it is done now ( since the helpers actually use the Bulk API ) the acknowledgement is returned for every iteration. This slows things down a lot. Unless of course you use the Bulk operations directly.

So to "re-cast" your values in modern versions, do this instead:

```
var bulk = db.play_sessions.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
var count = 0;

db.play_sessions.find({ "user_id": { "$type": 2 } }).forEach(function(doc) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
        "$set": { "user_id": NumberInt(doc.user_id) }
    });
    count++;

    if ( count % 10000 == 0 ) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.play_sessions.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    }
});

if ( count % 10000 != 0 ) 
    bulk.execute();
```

Bulk operations send all of their "batch" in a single request. In actual fact the underlying driver breaks this up into individual batch requests of 1000 items, but 10000 is a reasonable number without taking up too much memory in most cases.

The other optimization here is that the only items selected by the query are those that are presently a "string" by the **`$type`** operator to identify this. This could possibly speed things up if some of the data is already converted.

If indeed you have an earlier version of MongoDB and you are running this conversion on a collection that is not on a sharded cluster, then your other option is to use [`db.eval()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/).

Take **care** to actually **read** the content on that link though. This is not a good idea, and you should never use this in production and only as a last resort for one off conversion. The code is submitted as JavaScript and actually run on the server. As a result a high level of locking can and will occur while running. You have been *warned*:

```
db.eval(function() {
    db.play_sessions.find({ "user_id": { "$type": 2 } }).forEach(function(doc) {
        db.play_sessions.update(
            { "_id": doc._id },
            { "$set": { "user_id": NumberInt( doc.user_id ) } }
        );
    });
});
```

Use with caution and prefer the "batch" processing or even the basic loop on a machine as close as possible in network terms to the actual database server. Preferably on the server.

Also where version permits and you still deem the `eval` case necessary, try to use the Bulk operations methods anyway, as that is the greatly optimized approach.